# Pass context between siblings using context in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code where I am trying to get a value from one component to its sibling using the `context` api.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <TheButton />
      <Display />
    </div>
  );
}

export const NumberContext = React.createContext();

function TheButton() {
  return (
    <NumberContext.Provider value={"test"}>
      <button>Click me</button>
    </NumberContext.Provider>
  );
}

function Display() {
  const context = React.useContext(NumberContext);
  return <div>The answer {context}.</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

As you can see I am passing the 'test' value in the provider, but when the page renders all I see is "The answer ."

Here is a a codesandbox for the issue https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-forest-zjlc2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the fact that `context` gives you a  decoupled way of passing `props` the `Provider` still must be on a higher hierarchy. Provide your context from your `App` and consume it from children.

```
export const NumberContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
    const [foo, changeFoo] = useState('foo')
    return (
        <NumberContext.Provider value={{ foo, changeFoo }}>
            <TheButton />
            <Display />
        </NumberContext.Provider>
    );
}


function TheButton() {
    const { changeFoo } = useContext(NumberContext)
    return (
        <button onClick={() => changeFoo('bar')}>Click me</button>
    );
}

function Display() {
    const context = React.useContext(NumberContext);
    return <div>The answer {context.foo}.</div>;
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to say on click of the button then increase a counter using `useState`, and show that counter in the `Display` component?

Comment: Now you are providing from `App` changing from `Button` and showing on `Display`

Comment: Notice how `foo` and `setFoo` are part of App's local state

Comment: I see! That kind of makes it a bit messy, since now App will be defining states that should belong to other components?

Comment: In this example of course. But you won't do this in a real app. This is the use case for creating a `Provider` Component which holds all state that interest to a given piece of your application. The gist is to always hold the state in a higher component and provide it from there