# Pass state between sibling components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a simple ShoppinList. I have two components, `Form.js` and `List.j`. How can I display in `List.js` the items that are stored in `list` array in `Form.js` ? I don't want `useState` to be written in `App.js`, but would keep the logic separate in its own components.

**App.js:**

```
//Imporing Components
import Form from "./Components/Form";
import List from "./Components/List";

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="App">
          <header>
              <h1>Shopping List</h1>
          </header>
          <Form/>
          <List/>
      </div>
  )
}
```

**Form.js:**

```
/*Create a Component*/
const Form = () => {

    const [inputText,setInputText] = useState("")
    const [list,setList] = useState([])

    const submitBtn = (e) =>{
         e.preventDefault()  /*kein refresh tätigen*/
        setList([
            ...list,{inputText}
        ])
    }

    /*Funktion*/
    /*const inputTextHandler =  (e) => {
        setInputText(e.target.value)
    }*/

    return (
        <form>
            <input
                value={inputText}
                type="text"
                onChange={
                    (e) => setInputText(e.target.value)
                }
            />
            <button type="submit" onClick={submitBtn}>
                <i>Add</i>
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}
export default Form
```

**List.js:**

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const List = () =>{
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>{[List]}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}
export default List
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In React, `state` goes top to bottom. A nested component can update the `state` of a parent if a function defined in the parent has been passed to it as `prop`. Hence, what you wanna do is not possible (exchanging state between `List` and `Form`, two sibling components).

For this to work, you should have the state for the list in a parent component, `App.js` for example, this way:

```js
import Form from "./Components/Form";
import List from "./Components/List";
import {useState} from "react";


function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState([])
  return (

      <div className="App">
          <header>
              <h1>Shopping List</h1>
          </header>
          <Form list = {list} setList = {setList}/>
          <List list = {list} />
      </div>
  )
}
```

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";

const List = ({list}) =>{

    return(
        <div>
            <ul>{list.map(item => <li>"test"</li>)}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default List
```

```js
const Form = ({list, setList}) => {
    const [inputText,setInputText] = useState("")

    const submitBtn = (e) =>{
         e.preventDefault()  
        setList([
            ...list,{inputText}
        ])
    }

    return (
        <form>
            <input
                value={inputText}
                type="text"
                onChange={
                    (e) => setInputText(e.target.value)
                }
            />
            <button type="submit" onClick={submitBtn}>
                <i>Add</i>
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default Form
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do what you're asking as React only allows child components to accept state from parent components, it is a top-down process. I would recommend using a React "Context"; A context will allow you to have one component that can share state throughout the entire component tree without having to pass props down through child components. It's basically a store for the whole react app, that can be pulled wherever and whenever needed.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass props to sibling component without passing it to parent component.
Alternative way is to use state managers such as Redux, Effector or at least React Context.

The way React works:

```
import Form from "./Components/Form";
import List from "./Components/List";


function App() {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);


    const formSubmitHandler = (passedData) => {
        setList(passedData);
    }

    return (
         <div className="App">
             <Form onSubmitting={formSubmitHandler}/>
             <List list={list}/>
         </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: How can i do that with Context?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936042/pass-context-between-siblings-using-context-in-react) will help you with context.