# Share state between sibling components in React without unnecessary child re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From [Pass state between sibling components in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72314664/pass-state-between-sibling-components-in-react), it seems most convenient way to pass state across sibling components in React is to maintain the common state in the Parent.

However if any of the children updates the parent state, parent will re-render, causing all children to re-render.

I have a case like below (much more simplified version than what I have):

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     this.state = {a:1, b:2, c:3}
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
       <Child1 {this.state.a} onClick={this.setState((prev) => {...prev, b: prev.b+1})}>
       <Child2 {this.state.b} onClick={this.setState((prev) => {...prev, c: prev.c+1})}>
       <Child3 {this.state.c} onClick={this.setState((prev) => {...prev, a: prev.a+1})}>
    </div>
  }
}
```

If I click on Child1, it will change the parent state, parent will re-render, triggering everything to re-render, however Child3 doesn't actually have to re-render since value of `c` hasn't changed.

I tried defining Child3 as PureComponent, something like below:

```
class Child3 extends React.PureComponent {
   render() {
      console.log("rendering!")
      ...
   }

   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
      console.log("updated!")
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      console.log("mounted!")
   }

   // PureComponents don't have shouldComponentUpdate, and using Component class still never calls below on Parent state update anyway
   // shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
   //   console.log("should update?")
   //   return false
   // }
}
```

however changing parent state through Child1 prints:

```
rendering! // undesired re-rendering of Child3
mounted!   // Child3 mounts after re-rendering
State 'a' changed from 1 to 2 // I log parent state changes at each componentDidUpdate
mounted!   // Child3 mounts again? also not sure why twice (also curious about this but probably orthogonal issue)
```

I also tried adding below to Parent:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(){false}
```

So to prevent parent from re-rendering, thus not all children would re-render, hoping change in parent state would still reflect on the children. However that causes none of the Children to re-render, although I want to re-render Child2 if Child1 is clicked, etc.

from what I could find online, it seems like [memoize-one](https://github.com/alexreardon/memoize-one) is a suggested approach, with a drawback that we keep this component in memory. Another idea could be to use redux, but I want this to be self contained, not global.

So I am looking for a way to share state across children (probably through using parent's state), without triggering unnecessary updates of all children.

Comment: Consider switching to functional components, class components are kind of deprecated.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I intentionally chose class components because I would like to organize my code with class inheritance (eg. class ExampleComponent extends MonitoredFeature), I subjectively don't enjoy lambda/functional notation too much although I know there are few advantages to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any additional library for this, just use [`memo`](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) (for function components) or [`PureComponent`](https://react.dev/reference/react/PureComponent#purecomponent) or [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#shouldcomponentupdate) (for class components) to memoize your child components so they don't re-render when their props haven't changed.

You seem to be using class components, so here's a simple example with `PureComponent`:

```js
class Child1 extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        console.log("Rendering Child1");
        return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.a}</div>;
    }
}
class Child2 extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        console.log("Rendering Child2");
        return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.b}</div>;
    }
}
class Child3 extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        console.log("Rendering Child3");
        return <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.props.c}</div>;
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
        this.onChild1Click = this.onChild1Click.bind(this);
        this.onChild2Click = this.onChild2Click.bind(this);
        this.onChild3Click = this.onChild3Click.bind(this);
    }

    onChild1Click() {
        this.setState((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            b: prev.b + 1,
        }));
    }

    onChild2Click() {
        this.setState((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            c: prev.c + 1,
        }));
    }

    onChild3Click() {
        this.setState((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            a: prev.a + 1,
        }));
    }

    render() {
        console.log("Rendering Parent");
        return (
            <div>
                <Child1 a={this.state.a} onClick={this.onChild1Click} />
                <Child2 b={this.state.b} onClick={this.onChild2Click} />
                <Child3 c={this.state.c} onClick={this.onChild3Click} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Parent />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Notice that I've had to make the `onClick` functions stable rather than creating new ones every time as in your code (I've also fixed a few errors), since if you create new ones every time, that's a prop whose value changes, so even `PureComponent` would re-render.

---

Note that the React team call `class` components "legacy" now; from [the documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/legacy):

> These APIs are exported from the react package, but they are not recommended for use in newly written code.

So for new code, here's that same example using function components and `memo`:

```js
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

const Child1 = React.memo(({ onClick, a }) => {
    console.log("Rendering Child1");
    return <div onClick={onClick}>{a}</div>;
});
const Child2 = React.memo(({ onClick, b }) => {
    console.log("Rendering Child2");
    return <div onClick={onClick}>{b}</div>;
});
const Child3 = React.memo(({ onClick, c }) => {
    console.log("Rendering Child3");
    return <div onClick={onClick}>{c}</div>;
});

const Parent = () => {
    const [a, setA] = useState(1);
    const [b, setB] = useState(2);
    const [c, setC] = useState(3);

    const onChild1Click = useCallback(() => {
        setB((b) => b + 1);
    }, []);
    const onChild2Click = useCallback(() => {
        setC((c) => c + 1);
    }, []);
    const onChild3Click = useCallback(() => {
        setA((a) => a + 1);
    }, []);

    console.log("Rendering Parent");
    return (
        <div>
            <Child1 a={a} onClick={onChild1Click} />
            <Child2 b={b} onClick={onChild2Click} />
            <Child3 c={c} onClick={onChild3Click} />
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Parent />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Note I've used `useCallback` to, again, make the click functions stable.

With both, you can customize the memoization, via a callback with `memo` for function components or implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` for class components. (Beware that both the `memo` callback and `shouldComponentUpdate` return booleans, but they have opposite meanings: The `memo` callback is asking "are these the same?" so `true` means "don't render;" but `shouldComponentUpdate` is asking "should the component update," so `true` means "render.")

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! This works, I also realized in addition to defining inline functions which cause re-rendering, I was also defining inline Component classes while testing which also cause re-rendering. making them persist somewhere else was very helpful!