# Dependency Injection for adjacent components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to share state between two react components that are NOT parent/child, rather they are adjacent to each other.

In order to clarify as I have not seen others use the term adjacent components, here is an example of what I mean, app component that contains a Header, Login, and Home component (the Header, Login, and Home I am referring to as adjacent):

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

now from my header component I want  to access state from my login component. I understand I could bring the state into the app component instead, however the way I am doing it now with adjacent components is the way I was able to do it using the redux library.

I was under the impression that for dependancy injection specifically, redux has largely been replaced by useContext. What I did not realize until today was that useContext as defined in react documentation is only for parent/child components:

> Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without
> having to pass props down manually at every level.

So with react you can natively avoid the props drilling problem, however, is there a way in react to share state across adjacent components without using a state management library?

Comment: What do you mean by this statement?

"What I did not realize until today was that useContext as defined in react documentation is only for parent/child components".

If you were to use the context API to create a custom provider and then wrap your "adjacent" components both components will be able to access state within the provider. The new beta react docs have a really good context tutorial: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

Comment: Two components at the same level are typically called "siblings", that should help your search. Here's a related question you may find useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936042/pass-context-between-siblings-using-context-in-react